# Алгоритм нахождения кратчайшего пути между вершинами графа

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, графы

Заданы две вершины и между ними нужно найти кратчайший путь, граф неориентированный и не имеет весов. Пытался реализовать с помощью алгоритма Дейкстры, но во всех примерах ищется именно расстояние до вершин, а мне нужен путь. Если есть пример такого алгоритма (желательно на JS) - буду благодарен!

Comment: BFS вам в помощь

Comment: @tym32167 а как с его помощью найти какой путь является самым коротким, можно хотя бы вкратце алгоритм?

Comment: идете по узлам обходом в ширину, каждому узлу при посещении прописываете узел, из которого туда попали. Как дойдете до нужного узла, сможете вернуться назал к началу - то есть пройти кратчайший путь задом наперед.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо, вымучил с горем пополам)

Comment: https://qiao.github.io/PathFinding.js/visual/

Comment: А в Дейкстре нельзя запоминать, откуда пришли?..